# Error 'Cannot resolve directory' with personal public repository

Tags: go, go-modules

I cloned the repository to a new computer. But there was such a problem: `Cannot resolve directory 'my-repo'`

```
import (
  "github.com/my-git/my-repo/internal/handlers"
  "github.com/my-git/my-repo/internal/logger"
  "github.com/my-git/my-repo/internal/storage"
)
```

`my-repo` is my personal public repository, I used it successfully on another computer.

Project structure: https://imgur.com/a/yacjB80

go.mod:

```
module github.com/my-git/my-repo

go 1.21.5

require (
    github.com/go-chi/chi/v5 v5.0.11
    github.com/go-resty/resty/v2 v2.11.0
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.8.4
    go.uber.org/zap v1.26.0
)

require (
    github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/multierr v1.10.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.20.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
)
```

Tried to use `go mod tidy` and `go mod download`, nothing changed.

Comment: I just tried myself, and I can't resolve them either. https://github.com/my-git?tab=repositories doesn't list any public repositories. If you want to access private ones, you have to authenticate accordingly.

Comment: my-git and my-repo are just placeholders, there are no such names

Comment: Well, don't use other people's account names as placeholders then.